# How to send message on Facebook in android without the native app installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I need to send a message to Facebook friends using both native installed app or `webview` (Dialog).

I have tried using `FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder` **but it needs the native messenger app to be installed on device** .

What is the best way to achieve both messaging with and without native Facebook app. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but there's no support for that.

Comment: Thought so...but thanks..